# Efficiency on grid conversions

Tags: java, performance

Here's the deal, i have these two functions that i feel are very inefficient and I'm also as good as sure there are more efficient ways to do them.  So the "tile" variable is an int going from 0 - 24 and i need to get the x & y based on that int. (The tile variable resembles a specific button id in a 5x5 grid)

The first function:

`if (tile == 0 || tile == 5 || tile == 10 || tile == 15 || tile == 20) x = 0 
else if (tile == 1 || tile == 6 || tile == 11 || tile == 16 || tile == 21) x = 1;
else if (tile == 2 || tile == 7 || tile == 12 || tile == 17 || tile == 22) x = 2;
else if (tile == 3 || tile == 8 || tile == 13 || tile == 18 || tile == 23) x = 3;
else x = 4;`

The second function:

```
if(tile < 5) y = 0;
else if(tile < 10) y = 1;
else if(tile < 15) y = 2;
else if(tile < 20) y = 3;
else y = 4;
```

I think i might have found a more efficient way of doing the first one, although i'm not totally sure if it is more efficient.

```
x = tile;
while(x >= 5)
    x -= 5;
```

What would be the most efficient way of doing this?

Comment: You "feel" that they are inefficient -- but have you *measured* them to be inefficient?

Comment: In both cases, you might be able to make them more efficient by using math. Hint: modulus for first, integer division for the second.

Comment: I have not done any measurements, but from what i've heard, if statements are not the most efficient functions. Also, it's quite a lot of text written.

Comment: Have you learned [`%` (modulo) operator](http://mindprod.com/jgloss/modulus.html) yet?

Comment: @VelocityHD Whether `if` statements are more efficient depends on what you're doing. Branch prediction can make some if/else trees pretty darn fast. But in this case, I'd guess that math would be faster than branching...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though performance-wise this will probably be trivial, there is definitely a better way to do this in terms of readability.

```
x = (tile % 5); // modulus
y = tile / 5; // division
```

Comment: The minus 1 is not needed at all for both operations, I'm pretty sure.

Comment: @user3580294 you're right. Just removed it after looking at it for a minute.

Comment: Still see `-1` in the first. For example, `5 % 5 -1 == -1`

Comment: @PM77-1 looks like it's actually not needed at all. Totally blanked therem, thanks!